# Sequence error postgres 9 to 10

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, sequences, postgresql-10

I'm trying to migrate my PostgreSQL 9.6.3 to 10.4. The restore seems to work correctly on the data, but i'm losing the sequences.
I'm having erros like: "Column 'min_value' does not exists", "Column not found in pgSet: last_values"...
It seems that PG 10 has a different way of working with sequences. My question is: Is there a way to restore a backp from PG 9 to 10 without losing data from the sequences?

Thank you.

Comment: You might get better answers on the DBA site: dba.stackexchange.com.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that without editing the dump from 9.6 before loading it.

The correct way to upgrade a database with dump/restore is to use `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall` from the v10 installation to perform the dump. That is the supported way.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean "editing the dump from 9.6 before loading it" ?
When I will create the backup file, at the dumpOption1 and 2, I don't see anything about sequences.

Comment: Well, you create a backup by running `pg_dump`. You will have to use the `pg_dump` from PostgreSQL v10 to create a dump that can be loaded into v10. If you cannot do that, you'll have to edit the dump (your backup) until it loads into PostgreSQL v10. If it is a custom format dump, use `pg_restore` to convert it to a plain format dump.